# Opening existing database created with SQLiteStudio

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Currently the error message I get is that the file cannot be opened. All I'm trying to do is open my database, open my table and extract the information from this. Below is what I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ExerciseDatabase.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "ExerciseList";

SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

private void openDatabase(){
    myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("/databaseManipulation/assets/" + DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
openDatabase();
Cursor allData = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ExerciseList", null);
Log.e("TESTLOG", allData.toString());

}
}
```

From what I've read it seems to suggest creating a new database and overwriting it with my existing one, any help would be great

Comment: The normal way to proceed is by copying the db from the `assets` folder to the proper data directory, if not existing. Then use it from there, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

add this function

```
public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, 
            OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
            }
```

use by this code

```
try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() +
            "/databases";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {              
            f.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();

            //---copy the db from the assets folder into 
            // the databases folder---
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("MyDB"),
                new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/MyDB"));
            Log.i("esfandune", "esfandune");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: this from www.androidyou.ir

Comment: It seems to open the database file fine now although it can't find the table, keeps saying table doesn't exist. Any thoughts?

Comment: On further inspection it seems to not run the try catch @mohammed fathi jorabi

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
public class SystemHelper{

private final String DB_PATH;
private final String DB_NAME;
private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

public SystemHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "YOUR_DB_NAME_IN_ASSETS.db", null, 1);
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    DB_NAME = "YOUR_DB_NAME_IN_ASSETS.db";
    mContext = context;
    createDataBase();
    openDataBase();
}

public void createDataBase() {
    try {
        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        if (!mDataBaseExist) {
            Files.copyFromAssets(mContext, DB_NAME, DB_PATH);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    return mDataBase;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

public void openDataBase() {
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
}
```

and Files.copyFromAssets(mContext, DB_NAME, DB_PATH) method:

```
public static void copyFromAssets(Context context, String fileName, String path) {
    InputStream mInput = null;
    try {
        mInput = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
        File f = new File(path + fileName);
        if (!f.exists())
            f.createNewFile();
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```